# View in subclassing ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a VC `Home` which is a subclass of another VC `Base`. In the `Base` view controller I have assigned a background image and a view (which i want in common for every VC in my app). However, after this implementation, I am not able to add UI components to my `Home` VC, neither through Code nor through storyboard. Whatever component I add in storyboard does not appear when I run my app.

Can anyone suggest why is this happening and what needs to be fixed?

Comment: This may sound silly but did u name the storyboard's VC the file 'HomeVC' something?

Comment: *"In the 'Base' view controller I have assigned a background image and a view"* - how? Show some code, that probably does not work since you simply override the view property, is that correct?

Comment: can you show your code in viewController?

Comment: show some code or view hierarchy to understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you must be adding your background image in code (homeVC) and other elements through IB (in ChildVC).
Try using:

```
[self bringSubviewToFront: subView]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by this ways :

1. Create your BaseViewController

   ```
   class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "yourBGimg.png")!)
   }
   }
   ```
2. Create Your HomeViewController

   ```
   class HomeViewController: BaseViewController {

   }
   ```

Hope this will help you :)